# Objective-C and C

Tags: objective-c, c, compiler-errors

I try to use the "libmsrp", but when I try to compile the library, I have the following error:

```
$ make so
gcc -ggdb -shared -Wl,-soname,libmsrp.so.0 -o libmsrp.so.0.0.2 msrp.o msrp_session.o msrp_message.o msrp_relay.o msrp_switch.o msrp_callback.o msrp_network.o msrp_utils.o -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations  -lpthread
ld: unknown option: -soname
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [so] Error 1
```

So I change the -soname option to -dylib_install_name -Wl. After compile I have the following error:

```
$ make so
gcc -ggdb -shared -Wl,-dylib_install_name -Wl,libmsrp.dylib.0.0.2 -o libmsrp.dylib.0.0.2 msrp.o msrp_session.o msrp_message.o msrp_relay.o msrp_switch.o msrp_callback.o msrp_network.o msrp_utils.o -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations  -lpthread <p>
Undefined symbols:<p>
"_main", referenced from:
start in crt1.10.5.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [so] Error 1
```

So, I try to compile in a Objective-C project. I add the source and header files and compile the project.

I get the following errors:

```
command: MSRP_LIST_FREE(sessions, sessions_lock);

msrp.c:75: error: expected ';' before 'temp'
msrp.c:75: error: 'temp' undeclared (first use in this function)
msrp.c:75: error: 'next' undeclared (first use in this function)
msrp.c:75: error: expected ';' before 'temp'
msrp.c:75: error: 'previous' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

declaration:

```
#define MSRP_LIST_FREE(list, lock
if(!(list))
    return 0;
else {
    typeof((list)) temp = list, next = NULL;
    while(temp) {
        next = temp->next;
        MSRP_LIST_REMOVE((list), (lock), temp);
        temp = next
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, makefile deals with some defines which are not set while you are compiling from sources.
You should continue to fight with make to make it compile ;)
Probably, you should try to use gmake instead of make.

Answer (score 0):

`-soname` should be `-install_name` I think (not `-dylib_install_name`).  In any case when I make that change, it compiles cleanly.

This is what I had in my make file:

```
gcc -ggdb -shared -Wl,-install_name,libmsrp.so.0 -o libmsrp.so.0.0.2 ... etc.
```

Comment: I tried your idea, but don't work. I modified the Makefile, as you wrote, and then run the "make so" command.
gcc -ggdb -shared -Wl,-install_name,libmsrp.so.0 -o libmsrp.so.0.0.2 msrp.o msrp_session.o msrp_message.o msrp_relay.o msrp_switch.o msrp_callback.o msrp_network.o msrp_utils.o -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations  -lpthread 
Undefined symbols:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.5.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [so] Error 1

Any Idea?

Comment: Yes it does work.  I downloaded the package, made the change and it compiles just fine.  You must have changed something else.

Comment: I try...I delete every file and unrar and restart my mac. I download the library from the http://sourceforge.net/projects/libmsrp/ site. I replace the command: $(CC) -ggdb -shared -Wl,-install_name,libmsrp.so.0 -o libmsrp.so.0.0.2 $(OBJS) $(OPTS) $(LIBS)
Compile it: make all, but I get the same error:
Undefined symbols:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.5.o
You use 10.5 or 10.6 os x? I use 10.5

Comment: I'm using 10.6 and Xcode 3.2.3.  I guess that might be the difference.  You should check your linker docs (man ld) to see what the option is to set an internal install path.

Comment: Also try `gcc -ggdb -shared -Wl,-dylib,-Wl,-install_name,libmrsp.so.0...`

Comment: Thanks the answer! I compiled the library aug 24, but I go to vacations. I have a question: You could use the library on os x? Because I don't use correctly the endpoint on os x, but on Linux worked perfectly.

Comment: I didn't go beyond trying to compile it.  The first time I has ever seen it was when you asked your question :)